# crear restricciones a una en funcion de una fecha (mysql)

Tags: mysql

me gustaría que alguien me pudiera ayudar, tengo tres tablas una llamada "usuarios", otra llamada "actividades"  y la última que se llama control_actividades, actividades y usuarios tienen de PK un id, y en control actividades lo que pretendo es controlar que usuarios se apuntan y a que actividad se apuntan guardando la fecha en la que se apuntan.
Pero lo que no sé hacer es como controlar que un usuario solo se pueda apuntar a una actividad por día... alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: sube una imagen de tu modelo Entidad Relacion y te respondo la Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes validarlo obteniendo la cantidad de registros que hay asociados a un id de persona y a la fecha si la cantidad es superior a 1 ya se encuentra asociado a una actividad :

```
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   CONTROL_ACTIVIDADES
    WHERE  ID_PERSONA = 'ALGUN_ID_DE_PERSONA'
    AND    DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(FECHA, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

PD : si subes una imagen de tu modelo ER te puedo ayudar con tu query.